# Frisby Functional Test standards

Tags: node.js, functional-testing, frisby.js

I'm new to this and I have been searching for ways (or standards) to write proper functional tests but I still I have many unanswered questions. I'm using FrisbyJS to write functional tests for my NodeJS API application and `jasmine-node` to run them.

I have gone through Frisby's documentation, but it wasn't fruitful for me.

Here is a scenario:

- A guest can create a `User`. (No username duplication allowed, obviously)
- After creating a `User`, he can login. On successful login, he gets an Access-Token.
- A `User` can create a `Post`. Then a `Post` can have `Comment`, and so on...
- A `User` cannot be deleted once created. (Not from my NodeJS Application)

What Frisby documentation says is, I should write a test within a test.

For example (full-test.spec.js):

```
// Create User Test
frisby.create('Create a `User`')
    .post('http://localhost/users', { ... }, {json: true})
    .expectStatus(200)
    .afterJSON(function (json) {

        // User Login Test
        frisby.create('Login `User`')
            .post('http://localhost/users/login', { ... }, {json: true})
            .expectStatus(200)
            .afterJSON(function (json) {

                // Another Test (For example, Create a post, and then comment)

            })
            .toss();

    })
    .toss();
```

Is this the right way to write a functional test? I don't think so... It looks dirty.

I want my tests to be modular. Separate files for each test. 
If I create separate files for each test, then while writing a test for `Create Post`, I'll need a `User`'s Access-Token.

To summarize, the question is: How should I write tests if things are dependent on each other?
`Comment` is dependent on `Post`. `Post` is dependent on `User`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the by product to using NodeJS. This is a large reason I regret deciding on frisby. That and the fact I can't find a good way to load expected results out of a database in time to use them in the tests.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand - You basically want to execute your test cases in a sequence. One after the other.

But since this is javascript, the frisby test cases are asynchronous. Hence, to make them synchronous, the documentation suggested you to nest the test cases. Now that is probably OK for a couple of test cases. But nesting would go chaotic if there are hundreds of test cases.

Hence, we use sequenty - another nodejs module, which uses call back to execute functions(and test cases wrapped in these functions) in sequence. In the afterJSON block, after all the assertions, you have to do a call back - cb()[which is passed to your function by sequenty].

https://github.com/AndyShin/sequenty

```
var sequenty = require('sequenty');

function f1(cb){
    frisby.create('Create a `User`')
    .post('http://localhost/users', { ... }, {json: true})
    .expectStatus(200)
    .afterJSON(function (json) {
         //Do some assertions
         cb(); //call back at the end to signify you are OK to execute next test case
    })
    .toss();
}

function f2(cb){
    // User Login Test
    frisby.create('Login `User`')
        .post('http://localhost/users/login', { ... }, {json: true})
        .expectStatus(200)
        .afterJSON(function (json) {
              // Some assertions
              cb(); 
         })
     .toss();
}

sequenty.run(f1,f2);
```

Comment: NodeJs has its ways, but since this is so widely used I see solutions to most of the problem easily available. Nowadays.